# How do you upload a csv file in a repository on Github?

Tags: csv, github, repository

I know I can make a new file in a github repository, but there's no way to upload a certain file. I am trying to upload a csv file as part of a project on github, and I don't want to copy and paste it into a a text file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Copying and pasting is **not** how you upload files to github. Use a git client to push the files into the repository. 
To upload the file, make sure that you **add** it to the repository, **commit** everything and then push the changes to the repository.